# Perl: Display STDOUT and STDERR in different colors on Windows

Tags: windows, perl

I'm using Perl 5.22.1 with Win32::Console. I have scripts that run make and I thought it would be nice if I could output the errors in red. Win32::Console has handles for stdout and sterr so I thought I could give colors to the individual handles but if I modify stderr, then it also modifies stdout. Is there a way to do this with Win32::Console or another module.

test.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::Console;

my $stdout = new Win32::Console(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
my $stderr = new Win32::Console(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

sub testOutput
{
    print("Testing output\n");
    system("ls error");
    system("ls *.pl");
    print("\n");
}

testOutput();

$stdout->Attr($FG_BLUE);

testOutput();

$stderr->Attr($FG_RED);

testOutput();

$stdout->Write("stdout print\n");
$stderr->Write("stderr print\n");
```

The output
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because regardless of the apparent "stream" on which you invoke `Attr`, ultimately, both are connected to the console and all `Win32::Console` does is to [output a given sequence of control characters to the console](https://metacpan.org/dist/Win32-Console/source/Console.pm#L419).

If I understand correctly, you want the `stderr` output of `ls` to show in one color and the `stdout` output of `ls` to show up in another color. In that case, you might want to use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) to capture those streams and output them with the settings you want.